# Prove that $\ln(n)$ lies between the two sums

Tags: real-analysis, integration, logarithms

Prove that for $n\in \mathbb{N}$ we have
$$\sum_{k=2}^{n} \frac{1}{k}\leq \ln(n)\leq \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{k}$$

---

Here is what I know;
$$\ln(n) = \int_1^n \frac{1}{k}dk$$
From examining the graph of function $1/n$, I can see the first inequality, as all the rectangles (length = 1, height = $1/n$) lie below the curve $1/n$. But i think I should show this more thoroughly. Also I can't figure how to think about second inequality. Appreciate your help.

Comment: looks like left and right Riemann sums.  Integral should be from **1** to $n$

Comment: $$\ln(n)=\int_1^n \frac 1k dk$$

Comment: Yes, that was a typo. Thanks

Comment: The second inequality has the same nature as the first one. Just shift the argument of the function by 1.

Comment: I suggest that you draw a graph of $f(k)=1/k$ from $1$ to $10$. Partition the interval in nine pieces of length $1$, draw rectangles. I think there is no better way of learning this kind of inequalities without doing this.

Comment: Not a good idea to use $k$ to be a real, an integer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\ln n= \int_1^n\frac{1}{x}dx =\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\int_{k}^{k+1}\frac{1}{x} dx$$
Now if $k\le x\le k+1$, then $\frac{1}{k+1}\le\frac{1}{x}\le \frac{1}{k}$, so 
$$\sum_{k=2}^n\frac{1}{k}=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k+1} =\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\int_k^{k+1}\frac{1}{k+1}dx \le \underbrace{\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\int_{k}^{k+1}\frac{1}{x} dx}_{=\ln n} \le \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\int_{k}^{k+1}\frac{1}{k} dx = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k}$$

Comment: How is $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\int_k^{k+1}\frac{1}{k+1}dx \le \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\int_{k}^{k+1}\frac{1}{x} dx$?

Comment: If $f(x)\le g(x)$ and $I$ is any interval, then $\int_I f(x)dx\le \int_I g(x)dx$

Comment: $f(x)=\frac{1}{k+1}$ and $g(x)=\frac{1}{x}$.  Sorry I can't see how is $f(x)\leq g(x)$ here.

Comment: Aah never mind. $x /geq k$ in that integral. Makes sense.